# Retrieve value from input next to a button using THIS selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, input, this

I ran into this problem, I have two siblings, an input and a button which calls a function to retrieve the value in the input, but it keeps telling me that Value is Undefined...

Here's the "form":

```html
<li>
<input id="mem3" value="TestU4" disabled="">
<button id="del3" class="delmem" onclick="deleteBandMember();">remove</button>
</li>
```

Here's jQuery Code:

```js
function deleteBandMember() {
  var mmbr = $(this).prev("input").val();  //<-RETURNS UNDEFINED
}
```

I need to use This selector for there are too many dynamically-created inputs...
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `this` as parameter in `deleteBandMember` function as shown :-

HTML :-

```
<li>
<input id="mem3" value="TestU4" disabled="">
<button id="del3" class="delmem" onclick="deleteBandMember(this);">remove</button>
</li>
```

jQuery :-

```
function deleteBandMember(elem){
   var mmbr = $(elem).prev("input").val();
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1f93vpxs/)

Answer (score 2):

Directly using jQuery, you can attach a click handler:

HTML:

```
<li>
<input id="mem3" value="TestU4" disabled="">
<button id="del3" class="delmem">remove</button>
</li>
```

JS:

```
$('#del3').click(function(){
  var mmbr = $(this).prev("input").val();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

While Kartikeya is correct. I would suggest not using "onClick" attributes, its no longer a good practise to do so. Plus you are using jQuery so you can take advantage of that. So your code would look like:

```
$('#del3').click( function() {
  var mmbr =  $(elem).prev("input").val();
  // do more stuff. 
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an aside since the question has a good answer, you might want to consider [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) if you have a large number of inputs and buttons in your form. `jQuery` makes this very easy. Instead of attaching an event to each button, attach one event to an element that contains those elements (like `<form>`):

HTML

```
<form id="form">
...
  <li>
    <input id="mem3" value="TestU4" disabled=""></input>
    <button id="del3" class="delmem">remove</button>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input id="mem34" value="TestU44" disabled=""></input>
    <button id="del34" class="delmem">remove</button>
  </li>
...
</form>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#form').on('click', '.delmem', function() { deleteBandMember(this); });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yw0xsy5r/10/)

Comment: Awesome answer! This is very useful info, as I find it rather impossible to attach event handlers to each individual item!